# Not able to get the firebase token in Progressive Web Apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a `Progressive Web Apps` project which is using `firebase cloud` messaging service for push notifications. It was working fine but since last month, I am not able to receive push notifications anymore.

I checked and found out that the firebase access token was not getting generated on the client side.

Method call - `firebase.messaging().getToken()`

which in turn hits the following api :
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/connect/subscribe

But surprisingly, for one firebase account, I am able to generate an access token, but for another app, I am not able to generate the access token.

[image]
Click here for the error log in the chrome network tab

I should have got the access token by using `firebase.messaging().getToken()` just like I am getting in my other projects.

Comment: Are you using the correct [VAPID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_web_credentials_with)?

Comment: Still getting the same error even after passing the VAPID like this - firebase.messaging().getToken({ vapidKey: '<_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY>' })